# Activity indicator animation not working - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation, activity-indicator

I have this problem when I load the screen I start an activity indicator and call a function to get the data. At first the activity was shown but never starts then I ran each call (start activity & get data) in a different thread. The animation worked but only once when I try to load the screen another time it's stuck again until the data is loaded.
This is the viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //indicator
    indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    indicator.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
    indicator.color = commons.getButtonColor()
    indicator.center = self.view.center
    indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    self.view.addSubview(indicator)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("We finished that.")
        // only back on the main thread, may you access UI:
        self.indicator.startAnimating()
    }


    //connect to database
    commons.ref = Database.database().reference()

    //table view
    tableV.dataSource = self
    tableV.delegate = self
    tableV.tableFooterView = UIView()
    tableV.separatorStyle = .none
    tableV.allowsSelection = false

    //change left btn
    let leftButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(
        title: "",
        style: .done,
        target: self,
        action: #selector(backButtonPressed)
    )
    leftButtonItem.image = UIImage(named:"back")
    leftButtonItem.tintColor = commons.getButtonColor()
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButtonItem

    //style
    self.title = flag

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //get values
        if(self.flag == "Accounts"){
            self.color = "d0f0dd"
            self.getAccounts()
        }else if(self.flag == "Loans"){
            self.color = "f8ff90"
           self.getLoans()
        }else if(self.flag == "Cards"){
            self.color = "ffa669"
            self.getCards()
        }
    }

}
```

A screenshot when the screenis stuck:

[image]

Edit: The function to get data:

```
func getAccounts(){
    commons.ref.child("Accounts").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for item in snapshot.children {
            self.values.append(item as! DataSnapshot)
        }
        self.tableV.reloadData()
        self.indicator.stopAnimating()
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func getCards(){
    commons.ref.child("Cards").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.indicator.stopAnimating()
        for item in snapshot.children {
            self.values.append(item as! DataSnapshot)
        }
        self.tableV.reloadData()
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func getLoans(){
    commons.ref.child("Loans").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.indicator.stopAnimating()
        for item in snapshot.children {
            self.values.append(item as! DataSnapshot)
        }
        self.tableV.reloadData()
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: You're never calling `self.indicator.stopAnimating()`, so why would the activity indicator disappear?

Comment: Oh yes i calling it, in the function where i get the data, it's not a matter of appear/disappear, the indicator does not stsrt animating at all, the page is stuck untill the data is loaded then everything is fine.

Comment: That indicates that you are blocking the main thread somewhere. Please include all relevant functions, since in the code in your question there doesn't seem to be any problems that could cause your issue.

Comment: I guess you are getting data possibly from web service in main thread. Until the data arrives the ui will be frozen. Update your question with the code where you get your data. Make sure you dispatch the service to a non-main thread. @yasserh

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a common error in all 3 of your functions. You are not calling `stopAnimating` on all possible branches of your code, so if the completion handler gets called with `error`, your activity indicator will keep running.

I am not sure how Firebase's completion handlers are implemented, they might be dispatched to the main queue already, but to be absolutely safe, I'd also recommend dispatching the `stopAnimating` function call to the main thread to make sure you don't accidentally try to update the UI from a background thread.

```
func getAccounts(){
    commons.ref.child("Accounts").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for item in snapshot.children {
            self.values.append(item as! DataSnapshot)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.tableV.reloadData()
            self.indicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.indicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    }
}
```

You should make the same changes to your other two functions.

Comment: Thank you for responding but the problem still occurs, the indicator work at first but if i visisted the page again the ui is frozen.

Comment: @yasserh you mean if you move from the view controller in question to another, then back, the data is not updated? `viewDidLoad` is only called once, when the class instance is loaded in memory, so if you want to reload data when navigating back and forth between viewcontrollers, you should call the functions updating your UI from `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Of course not, this is the flow: ServicesList -> accounts (indicator working) now back to servicesList -> accounts (ui frozen) so the viewDidLoad is called for sure.

Comment: Question: could the UI be affected by previous screens? Also other animations in different screens are not working.